# How to set one component to the left div, and another one to the right div in angular8?

Tags: angular, router-outlet

I have `app.component.html` page which contain three components:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-content></app-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

In my `header.component.html` I have this two buttons:

```
<div class="hor-menu hor-menu-light hidden-sm hidden-xs">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="navbarItem" id="firstNavbarItem">
      <a [routerLink]="['./addLeft']" (click)="addActiveClass($event)">
        Add left <span class="selected"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbarItem" id="secondNavbarItem">
      <a [routerLink]="['./addRight']" (click)="addActiveClass($event)">
        Add right <span class="selected"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I click on button "`Add left`", I want to change my route and set my component into the left div of `app-content` component. When I click on button "`Add right`", I want to set my component into the right div. Here is my code in `content.component.html` component:

```
<div class="leftContent">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="rightContent">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

In my `app.module.ts` I have:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
  path: 'addLeft',
  component: AddLeft,
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
  path: 'addRight',
  component: AddRight,
  pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: See this: https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you should be using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in two places on the same component but you could try using `*ngIf`

```
<div class="leftContent" *ngIf="left">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="rightContent" *ngIf="right">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

than inside of your .ts file add `right: boolean = false` & `left: boolean = false` variables to it. than in your addActiveClass() method do something like:

```
addActiveClass(event, position) {
  ...
  if(position === 'right') {
     right = true;
     left = false;
  } else {
     left = true;
     right = false;
  }
  ...
}
```

you will probably have to use a service with BehaviorSubject to communicate between the two components https://blog.angulartraining.com/rxjs-subjects-a-tutorial-4dcce0e9637f